# ms access: simple subtraction, wrong answer

Tags: vba, ms-access

181.72 - 181.00 = 0.719999999999999

Why does Access do this? How can I get the correct answer of 0.72

Comment: Use `CDec(181.72) - 181` but read the answers in the linked question to understand why.

Comment: thanks @AhmedAbdelhameed,  this gets the right output but unfortunately this CDec() doesn't work in queries or reports where I need to use it. I could use a custom VBA function but would prefer to avoid it if possible.

Comment: You probably should have specified where you needed to use it in your question then. It makes a difference.

Comment: Have you tried just formatting it in the report after it's calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use *Currency* as data type (also for your table fields) for amounts and quantities that require no more than four decimals:

```
Result = CCur(181.72) - CCur(181.00)
Result -> 0.72
```

For more decimals, use *Decimal*:

```
Result = CDec(181.59898) - CDec(181.00)
Result -> 0.59898
```

For use in a query, CDec will fail, so write a function to call it:

```vb
Public Function CVDec(ByVal Value As Variant) As Variant

    Dim Result As Variant

    Result = CDec(Value)

    CVDec = Result

End Function
```